# Is there a way to deploy a contract using bytecode only (to Ropsten ...)?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, remix, contract-deployment

One solution on medium.com describes how to do that via myetherwallet but it's the old verion of myetherwallet where you can switch between ropsten/mainnet - right now I can't find how to switch to ropsten...

I've deployed on ropsten with both remix and truffle but both required .sol solidity sourcecode and not bytecode? Thanx!

Comment: You can do it with a simple web3 script.

Comment: thanks will have a look at web3...i am sending transactions on web3 via python but never had the need to deploy contract, hope it's not super difficult...

Comment: Do you have its abi? If yes, then I can give you the scrip for that

Comment: no unfortunately, just found someone having the same issue: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70774/deploying-contract-using-bytecode

Comment: another user claims it's possible if you know the arguments for deployment...so at least this means i should be able to re-deploy on ropsten deployed contracts on mainnet that don't have their source verified...i mean since since etherscan gives both bytecode and arguments of deployment...

Comment: The arguments for deployment are there (on etherscan, for example), if you know the address