# How to clone(fork) a smart contract with only bytecodes deployed on etherscan.io (without abi and source code)?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, opcode

How to clone(fork) a smart contract with only bytecodes deployed on etherscan.io (without abi and source code)?

First, I try to submit the same bytecodes from etherscan.io using web3, but it failed. The submitted bytecodes were tampered by signature.

Second, I try to deploy by geth, but it needs abi, which I cannot find on etherscan.io

Last but not least, I know the msg.data structure, eg, (address to, address from,   uint256 amount)

[Deploying contract using byteCode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70774/deploying-contract-using-bytecode)

"Actually the data of deployed contract transaction is bytecode concatenate with abi encoded of constructor parameters."
"If you know inputs of constructor, you can use ethereumjs-abi to deploy contract."

but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need an abi to deploy. deploying with just bytecodes is possible using etherjs

Comment: This was tagged solidity.